# Java Date Parsing from string

Tags: java, date, datetime

I'm trying to parse a `String` into `Data`, I create the DataParser, in according to date format, the code I wrote is this:

```
    String date_s = "04-May-2017 17:28:27";
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    Date date;
    try {
        date = formatter.parse(date_s);
         System.out.println(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

When I execute this, I got always an exception

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "04-May-2017 17:28:27"
```

I don't understand why the data is not parsed, someone can help me?

Comment: Currently you're using your system locale (and time zone). If the system locale doesn't have "May" as an abbreviated month name, that would cause problems. You should probably specify `Locale.ENGLISH` when constructing the `SimpleDateFormat`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This thread of answers would not be complete without the modern solution. These days you should no longer use `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`, but switch over to the newer date and time classes:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter 
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
    LocalDateTime dateTime;
    try {
        dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(date_s, formatter);
        System.out.println(dateTime);
    } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
```

This prints

```
2017-05-04T17:28:27
```

(`LocalDateTime.toString()` returns ISO 8601 format) If leaving out `Locale.ENGLISH`, on my computer I get

```
Text '04-May-2017 17:28:27' could not be parsed at index 3
```

Index 3 is where it say `May`, so the message is somewhat helpful.

`LocalDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter` were introduced in Java 8, but have also been backported to Java 6 and 7.

Answer (score 0):

the string you want to parse is local dependent (the word **May** is English), so the jvm is not able to infer that may is the month of may in English

define the formatter using the constructor qith the locale.

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss",Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need another constructor with a `Locale` that supports `MMM` (**May**)

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss",Locale.US)
```

or using standard format `dd-MM-yyyy` with month digits.
(Sorry, in the meantime the answer was already posted)